# SVM Classification Plot in R

Tags: r, svm

I am a beginner in R. When fit an SVM model in R, I get a classification as below Where the decision boundary is a curve:

[image]

But I would rather have one as below Where the decision boundary is a smooth line.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you'll be able to change it based on the kernel setting and changing the value of degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the kernel used to train your model from (probably currently used) rbf to `linear`. Depending on the library used this parameter might be passed in a different way, but ultimatively this is all you need.

Comment: To clarify it, i have used "linear" kernal throughout this code yet i do not get a line. Moreover, i have used "e1071" library and i do not know if it causes any problems.

Comment: Hi lejlot, I run the following chunk of code in R:                       library(e1071)
set.seed(1)
x<-matrix(rnorm(40),ncol=2)
y<-rep(c(-1,1),c(10,10))
x[y==1] = x[y==1]+1
plot(x, col=(3-y))
dat=data.frame(x=x,y=as.factor(y))
dat
svmfit=svm(y~.,data=dat,kernal="linear",cost=10,scale=FALSE)
plot(svmfit,dat)

Comment: It should be "kernel", not "kernal"

Comment: You are spot on, leilot. Now i get what i want. Thank You Very Much.